# Best method to compare data between 2 different databases on separate servers

Tags: validation, hadoop, db2, rdbms

We are migrating data from DB2 database to Hadoop. The migration really is running `select * from table1` on DB2, exporting it to a delimited file, taking that file and putting it Hadoop. DB2 and Hadoop reside on different servers, different network. We need to run some validation steps to make sure that the data that is extracted from DB2 has *entirely* been imported to Hadoop. So, just running `select count(1) from table1` on both the systems would not help since we could have cases where some column values could not be imported due to specific character issue(e.x. newline etc).

What would be the best method to programmatically test that data is identical on both the systems?

P.S: Both Hadoop and DB2 are running on RHEL, so if any Linux specific tools that would be helpful in this process can be included.

Comment: Best according to what criteria? Also, wouldn't a case where _"some column values could not be imported due to specific character issue"_ be exactly the thing you wanted to discover?

Comment: @mustaccio: Best == reliable and within reasonable time. I would prefer not having the data validation to run for hours. And yes, I would still want to discover issues that would be on data import. Why did you think I do not want it? Just trying to understand if I did not write something correctly in the post.

Comment: If something is not _imported_, the entire row is usually rejected, so `select count(1)...` would help. And with you not mentioning the data volume in question, it's impossible to say if running "for hours" is "reasonable" or not. Re-exporting imported data from Hadoop into delimited files, _sorted by the same key as the original export_, and running a `diff` on both might be one option.

Comment: @mustaccio: Good point, currently we are looking at 4-6 GB files that are generated from DB2. So running `cksum` is what I am planning to do on the data files generated from DB2 and Hadoop. Do you think its good enough solution for data validation?

Comment: I don't know. Is it good enough for you? I'd still choose `diff` as `cksum` or similar will be sensitive to even a simple misplaced whitespace character, such as `\n` at the end of the file, which is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I would move ahead with cksum for now and see how it works out for me. I will wait for a couple of days to see if anyone has other recommendations before closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "best" way, but my approach would be:

1. As as one of the previous posters has suggested, export data from Hadoop to a delimited file and run a diff against the DB2 import files. This is probably the easiest method.
2. Write a simple utility which connects to both databases simultaneously, fetches data from two tables to compare, and compares the result set. Having Googled a bit, seems like there are some utilities out there already - for example http://www.dbsolo.com/datacomp.html.

Hope this helps.